# setUser.map no es una funcion, alguien me puede decir q hago mal...les quedare agradeido

Tags: fetch, map

[image][![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2][![me arroja el error userState.map no es una funcion ][error al querer hacer una peticion con fetch no doy con la solucion]

```js
const DisplayTable = (id, firstName) => {
        const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
        const [search, setSearch] = useState();
        useEffect(() => {
            obtenerDatos()
        }, [])

        const obtenerDatos = async () => {
            const response = await fetch("https://dummyjson.com/users",)
            const { users } = response.json();
            setUsers(users)
        }
        return (
            <div className="row">


                <ul>
                    {
                        setUsers.map((item) => (
                            <li key={item.id}> {item.firstName}</li>
                        ))
                    }
                </ul>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]<!--

Comment: hola Dario, Para que podamos ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código, edita tu pregunta elimina las imágenes y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar), y si recibes errores, muestranos cuales son.

Comment: El código y los mensajes de error siempre _como texto, con formato_. Además, coloca _tal cual_ el error que aparece. Lee [ask] y pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.